# Extra arguments for __str__ and __format__

Tags: python, global-variables

I am writing an application where I want to build command lines and run external processes. The command line strings need to allow for some kind of variable interpolation, so I chose to use the regular `str.format()` method.

Problem is, that some of the values I want to interpolate are dependent on an external context that is passed from the outside, but I don't see any way to forward it.

For example:

```
class SomeObject:
    def get_path(self, context):
        return context.directory / self.name

def x(context, some_object):
    # This doesn't work, but illustrates what I would like to do:
    return "gzip {0.get_path(1)}".format(some_object, context)
```

The only idea I have is to put the context into a global variable or into some_object, but that doesn't feel pythonic enough :-).

I am using python3, but python2 solutions would also be interesting.

Edit: The format string (`"gzip {0.get_path(1)}"` in this example) is actually passed from the ouside as well, so I can't move the `.get_path(1)` to the arguments of the `format` call. I oversimplified this when making the example.

Comment: so what you need is to find path of `dir` where python script executed ?

Comment: Why are you trying to divide a directory by a name? Division is for numbers.

Comment: I suspect you mean `return context.directory + '/' + self.name`

Comment: @Barmar He's probably using `pathlib`.

Comment: Assuming you are using `subprocess`, `x` should probably return `["gzip", "...".format(...)]`. Passing a list containing the program and its arguments is superior to trying to properly quote everything in a single string.

Comment: @chepner Yes, I'm passing a list, I just wanted to simplify the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple. All that's needed is a wrapper around `some_object` that adds the `context`. Like this:

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, o, context):
        self._o = o
        self._context = context
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._o, "get_" + name)(self._context)
```

... and use it like this:

```
return "gzip {0.path}".format(Wrapper(some_object, context))
```